# Groovy MockFor demands not acting as expected for stream

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, stream, mocking

I wanted to create a unit test verifying that a stream was closed. My class decorates the stream it receives with DataputStream, which seems to break the mocking demands feature.

```
void testBadMock() {
    def mockInputClass = new MockFor(InputStream)
    mockInputClass.demand.with {
        close() {}
    }

    def mockInput1 = mockInputClass.proxyInstance()
    mockInput1.close()
    mockInputClass.verify mockInput1 // passes

    def mockInput2 = mockInputClass.proxyInstance()
    new DataInputStream(mockInput2).close()
    mockInputClass.verify mockInput2 // fails
}
```

The specific error message:

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: verify[0]: expected 1..1 call(s) to 'close' but was called 0 time(s).

I checked the source code for DataInputStream, and as expected, the stream passed into the constructor is the object which it delegates the close() method call to.

```
def fakeInput = [close: {println 'I was called'}] as InputStream
new DataInputStream(fakeInput).close() // prints 'I was called'
```

I see no reason why my mock object is not seeing the close() method call.

Answer (score 1):

A potential workaround:

```
def mockInput2 = mockInputClass.proxyInstance() 
new DataInputStream([close: { mockInput2.close() }] as InputStream).close() 
mockInputClass.verify mockInput2
```